# I can't access the admin panel links as I click it shows 403 error

Tags: htaccess, errors, ssl

I am working on the following [website](https://www.jobgoround.com/). when I login into the Dashboard and click on any item on admin panel such as post or pages I get the following error:

> You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/options-general.php on this server.
>   Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I am also not able to navigate to the pages except homepage and I found the following error on other pages:

> The requested URL /job-interview/ was not found on this server.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

But the pages exists on the website.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

You might just need to flush permalinks. (Navigate to Settings > Permalinks and click "Save Changes") If you can't navigate to the permalinks page because of the error, you could try one of the other suggestions [here](https://www.webhostinghero.com/3-ways-to-flush-the-rewrite-cache-in-wordpress/)

Obviously make a backup of your database before performing any of them.

If that doesn't work there may be a permissions issue. It's generally suggested that the folders be set to 755 and files to 644. You can read more about WP file permissions [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/)

Comment: can you please let me know which folders should have 755

Comment: All folders, really. If you have ssh access you can use these: `find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755` and `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644`